# time conversion from apache phoenix to spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-phoenix

I am trying to insert phoenix data into spark, found that the date is changing after inserting into spark. For ex: Date in Phoenix is showing as 2017-10-10 but when same is seen in spark it is showing as 2017-10-11.

Did anyone else face the same issue.

Comment: Could you please add the code that you are trying.

Comment: You may want to check what is native timezone? is it all UTC?

Comment: I changed the timezone to CST timezone in Phoenix in hbase-site.xml.

Comment: Found the issue. It was issue with my local desktop timezone.spark was taking my desktop timezone hence the issue. When i changed the timezone on my desktop issue was resolved. Thanks.